# using 'new' operator in MS windows 64bit dll causes problems loading dll

Tags: windows, dll, 64-bit

MS Windows 10, MinGW64bit, Codeblocks 20:03

I have code that was previously in 32bit and working perfectly.  Rewriting and changing to 64 bit and running into problems.

I used codeblocks to generate a bare bones dll project and I've tracked this down to using the c++ "new"  (note this is probably not a codeblocks issue but that is my tool Im using)

If I build the dll with GCC MinGW64bit, and include ***anywhere in the code*** - even in an unused function -  when I try to load the library I get a null pointer.
Commenting out the one line (below) and everything works perfect.  DLL loads, runs etc.  The ONE LINE kills it.

```
// this causes the DLL to not load
int* ptrx = new int[10]
```

In a C++ calling program I just get a null pointer when I call LoadLibrary
If I try to call in using python and its tools it says:  "could not find module xxxxxxx or one of it's dependencies"

Is there a windows DLL or something that "new" is calling or something else I need for x64 that Im missing? Like I said - code runs fine unless I use the "new" operator anywhere in the DLL.

I tried

```
#include <new>
```

Same issue.  Code w/ or w/o the line runs fine as a 32BIT dll.

Comment: *one of its dependencies*, ensure the runtime DLLs are deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the only thing that is needed is to (in CODEBLOCKS) is to set the compiler **-static** option.